# How to find Xpath of specific HTML tags found using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

So, I have been trying to create an automation script. I have various Google Forms and they have a varying amount of input fields.

(The forms are not limited to Google Form they can be of any type, but they all have `input` tag in them)

So, what I want to do is ...

Finding all input tags in the Google Form using beautifulsoup and finding their xpath that can be used by selenium to click on them for automation.

[Look at this Google Form for a better overview](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSctPCwcVoji4AyGJOG40PukgBUt1_7XiUuFWxEs4EUXc-YH7g/viewform?usp=sf_link)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSctPCwcVoji4AyGJOG40PukgBUt1_7XiUuFWxEs4EUXc-YH7g/viewform?usp=sf_link')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
input_list = soup.find_all('input')
for input in input_list:
    print(input)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<input aria-describedby="i.desc.921080226 i.err.921080226" aria-label="Q1" autocomplete="off" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="" dir="auto" jsname="YPqjbf" name="entry.1872775733" tabindex="0" type="text" value=""/>
<input aria-describedby="i.desc.1125747839 i.err.1125747839" aria-label="Q2" autocomplete="off" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="" dir="auto" jsname="YPqjbf" name="entry.962306793" tabindex="0" type="text" value=""/>
<input aria-describedby="i.desc.1262061940 i.err.1262061940" aria-label="Q3" autocomplete="off" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="" dir="auto" jsname="YPqjbf" name="entry.330218692" tabindex="0" type="text" value=""/>
<input aria-describedby="i.desc.249579406 i.err.249579406" aria-label="Q4" autocomplete="off" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="" dir="auto" jsname="YPqjbf" name="entry.1162632557" tabindex="0" type="text" value=""/>
<input name="fvv" type="hidden" value="1"/>
<input name="draftResponse" type="hidden" value='[null,null,"-8500811055209088861"]
'/>
<input name="pageHistory" type="hidden" value="0"/>
<input name="fbzx" type="hidden" value="-8500811055209088861"/>
```

So, I am able to find the input elements but how to get their xpath so that I can use those xpath to use selenium for filling those forms?

Comment: Check the linked answer, it has a couple of workable approaches.

Comment: Yes, I found [xpath_soup](https://gist.github.com/ergoithz/6cf043e3fdedd1b94fcf) approach mentioned on the above answer on `Gist GitHub`. Anyway, thank you for the comment.